# Cannot revoke permissions granted to the application from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, office365-apps

I have the multitenant application which requires permissions to the Exchange Online service. Users can grant the permissions via consent screen and everything works perfect. But I don't know how to revoke the granted permissions.

- I see my application in the user's applications list on  https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/default.aspx,
- I can select it and click "Remove" from the drop down menu, press "Remove" again in the dialog asking "Are you sure you would like to remove this application?" and get "The application has been successfully removed." confirmation,
- but the application stays in the application list (I see the same behavior in Microsoft Edge and Firefox browsers).

So how to revoke the granted permissions?

Comment: Vlad - is there a chance that this application was explicitly assigned to you by your admin?  We'll try and repro the issue.

Comment: Dan, I have multitenant application registered in my developer Azure AD. I also have trial Office 365 account with several test users. In my web app I follow to [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) requesting the authentication code/access token. I redirect user to Azure Sign In screen (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize) with "promt=consent", user grants access to my web app clicking "OK" button on the consent screen (and I believe that it must be _user consent screen_) and my application works.

Comment: Dan I also created support ticket #615081994195096 through Office 365 Admin Portal, I believe that you can access my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad - I have repro'd this particular issue when I tried this last night. This morning the app tile for the revoked app was no longer present, and when I tried to go to the app I was asked to consent. The directory platform (Azure AD) that underpins and stores consent grants is currently experiencing some replication and caching delays that mean that there'll be delays between removing/revoking the app and revocation actually happening.  Folks are investigating but I don't have an ETA for resolution.

I'll try and get back to you when some of these issues have been resolved, but until then I'm afraid that removing apps will experience some delays.

**UPDATE:**  We discovered that there was actually a problem with the Access panel (My Apps page) itself.  I believe that this has now been fixed (sorry for any inconvenience caused).  Please verify that all is good now.  This *may* require revoking again on the My Apps page.

HTHs,

Comment: Dan - thank you for information and your assistance. In my case I waited more than 24 hours and the app tile still exists...